# SQL: Fill column from other table with different identifier/key and different number of data set

Tags: sql, set, distinct, identifier

Assuming the `dataTarget` column is empty, how do I fill it with data from the `dataSource` like shown below?

*Source*

```
id      otherSubId  dataSource
------------------------------
4000    10          DataA
4000    20          DataB
4000    30          DataC
4000    40          DataD
6000    1000        DataAA
6000    2000        DataBB
6000    3000        DataCC
6000    4000        DataDD
```

*Target*

```
id      subId   dataTarget
--------------------------
4000    100     DataA
4000    200     DataB
4000    300     DataC
6000    100     DataAA
6000    300     DataCC
6000    400     DataDD
6000    500     
6000    200     DataBB
```

Please note that -

- `DataD` from `dataSource` is not used
- `dataTarget` with an `id` value of `6000` and a `subId` value of `500` is left empty because no more data for the last set.

I am thinking creating a `tempId` column filled with sequential number needed (1, 2, 3, ...) for each unique `id` ordered by `otherSubId` on both tables and combine it with `id` to create something to connect between both tables, but I want to know if someone has a better approach without altering the table.

Comment: What's your RDBMS?

Comment: It's undecided for now, but lets say MySQL/PostgresQL.

Comment: Minor improvements to English usage made.  Tables presented separately.  `DataD`, `dataSource`, etc. formatted as code fragments (to format part of a line, rather than the whole line, as a code fragment, highlight the fragment and click on the `{}` button or place a ``` character on either side of the fragment)

Comment: How are `otherSubId` and `subId` related?  How do you choose which value from the source table is placed in a certain record's value of `dataTarget` in the target table?

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to basically mimic the plan you have for a tempid, but all within one query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, subID, dataTarget, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY subID asc) RN
      FROM target
     ) T
JOIN (SELECT id, othersubID, dataSource, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY othersubID asc) RN
      FROM source
     ) S ON S.id = T.id 
        AND S.RN = T.RN
```

The update would be:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.dataTarget = S.dataSource
FROM (SELECT id, subID, dataTarget, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY subID asc) RN
      FROM target
     ) T
JOIN (SELECT id, othersubID, dataSource, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY othersubID asc) RN
      FROM source
     ) S ON S.id = T.id 
        AND S.RN = T.RN
```

I'm also curious how representative your example data is of the actual table.  If it *really* looks just like that, you can add or remove a `0` in your join predicate:

```
SELECT *
FROM Target T
JOIN Source S ON T.id = S.id
             AND (t.subId * 10 = s.othersubID OR
                  t.subId / 10 = s.othersubID)
```

This should work in any RDBMS, assuming `subID` is not a string.  If it is, you have to concatenate or remove a `0` instead of doing math.